# calculator class execution error"name not defined"

Tags: python, class

I am new to python , and for the assignment the problem was given to me to make a calculator :
in which after defining mathematical functions i should "-  Define another method named execute_command that takes two numbers and a string named command"
this part is confusing me the most and i have written the below code for this , which in turn showing an error "the class c1 is not defined "even though i have initialised the class instance , could you please tell me where i am wrong?

```
class Calculator():
    def __init__(self,a,b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
    def add(self):
        return self.a + self.b
    def sub(self):
        return self.a - self.b
    def mult(self):
        return self.a * self.b
    def div(self):
        return self.a / self.b
    def execute_command(self, cmd):
        self.cmd = cmd
        if cmd == "Add":
            Calculator.add
        if cmd == "Sub":
            Calculator.sub
        if cmd == "Mul":
            Calculator.mult
        if cmd == "Div":
            Calculator.div 


a = int(input('Enter First number : '))
b = int(input('Enter Second number : '))        
cl = Calculator(a,b)
c1.execute_command(cmd=input('Enter the function to be performed : ').casefold())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was because you mistook the letter l for number 1. You also made a few mistakes. You can't complete the addition function as a static function when the class remembers the value of numbers. Here's your working code

```
class Calculator():
    def __init__(self,a,b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
    def add(self):
        return self.a + self.b
    def sub(self):
        return self.a - self.b
    def mult(self):
        return self.a * self.b
    def div(self):
        return self.a / self.b
    def execute_command(self, cmd):
        print(cmd)
        if cmd == "add":
            return self.add()
        if cmd == "sub":
            return self.sub()
        if cmd == "mul":
            return self.mult()
        if cmd == "div":
            return self.div()


a = int(input('Enter First number : '))
b = int(input('Enter Second number : '))        
cl = Calculator(a,b)
print(cl.execute_command(cmd=input('Enter the function to be performed : ').casefold()))
```

Comment: thank you , and also the typo was there for "mul" instead of "mult " , and with your help i solved this thank you.

Answer (score 1):

For the requirement above you have to make a function which accepts three parameters two are the no. and third is the operation name. So you can try this code :

```
class Calculator:
def execute_command(self, a, b, cmd):
    self.cmd = cmd
    self.a = a
    self.b = b
    if cmd == "Add":
        total = a+b
        print("Output after "+cmd+": "+str(total))
    if cmd == "Difference":
        total = a - b
        print("Output after "+cmd+": "+str(total))
    if cmd == "Multiplication":
        total = a * b
        print("Output after "+cmd+": "+str(total))
    if cmd == "Division":
        total = a / b
        print("Output after "+cmd+": "+str(total))

c = Calculator()
c.execute_command(8, 2, "Division")
```